# When does Elasticsearch client's ping method return false?

Tags: elasticsearch

Es documentation mentions that ping can return true or false, if the ES server is down the method throws exception, so not sure when it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The way how to handle the response depends on the client library you use. For example, the Ruby client checks the response code to decide which to return `true` or `false`.

```rb
perform_request(method, path, params, body).status == 200 ? true : false
```

See: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/ping.rb

If the ping request failed due to connection failure, it throws an exception without returning status code. In such a case, an exception is thrown instead of `false`. Therefore, `false` is returned if the response code of `HEAD` request is not 200 without any connection failure.

It would be good to take a look at the implementation of the client code you are using.